# Potential issues with adding a 90° bend to shower waste?

Tags: plumbing, shower, drain

Are there any potential issues with putting a 90° bend straight from a shower drain into a 50mm waste pipe? It then falls 10mm over a 1m span into a waste manifold.

Comment: Is that the only bend? in that branch? One or even a few aren't a concern.

Comment: It's the only one but it's straight off the drain, I'd be concerned it will cause flow issues, though can't say for sure.

Comment: Almost every pipe in the world has at least one bend. It won't be an issue. Use a standard long-radius (sweep) ell and don't worry a bit. Not much gets down shower drains anyway with the hardware usually present at the top of it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connecting an elbow directly to the shower strainer is not a problem, 2" hopefully.  Use as long of radius bend as you can. Keep a good slop in the drain line. Shower drains only handle water and not very much at a time. They rarely clog.